# SQL injection in loop doesn't work

Tags: php, mysql, loops, code-injection

```
        <?php
include '../connectdb.php';


$sqlNAME = 'INSERT INTO group_general (group_name)
VALUES (?)';

if($statementNAME = $connect->prepare($sqlNAME)) {

    $statementNAME->bind_param(

        "s",
        $_POST['groupName']
        );

    $statementNAME->execute();
}

$groupName = $_POST['groupName'];

$selectGROUPID = 'SELECT * FROM group_general WHERE group_name = "'.$groupName.'"';

$resultGROUPID = $connect->query($selectGROUPID);

if ($resultGROUPID->num_rows > 0) {
    $rowGROUPID = $resultGROUPID->fetch_assoc();
}

/* The error is somewhere around here~ish */

for ($x=0; $x<sizeof($_POST['addedUsers']); $x++) { 
    $rowUSERS[$x] = $_POST['addedUsers'][$x];

    $sqlUSERS = 'INSERT INTO group_users (user_name, group_id)
    VALUES ("'.$rowUSERS[$x].'", "'.$rowGROUPID['group_id'].'")';

    if($statementUSERS = $connect->prepare($sqlUSERS)) {


    if ($statementUSERS->execute()) {

        echo "Successfully created the group!";

    }
     else {
    echo "Failed to create the group...";
}
}
}
?>
```

So my issue is whenever a user selects multiple people (so the array $rowUSERS[] becomes more than only the 0 value), it only inserts the first selected user into the DB while it actually should loop through every selected user and insert it one by one. I really don't know what I did wrong here. Can you please look at it and help me?

Comment: Do `var_dump($_POST['addedUsers']);` and tell us what it is showing?

Comment: It says: C:\wamp64\www\INFORMATICA\forum\Nieuw\V4test2\code\php\groups\addUserToGroup.php:47:
array (size=2)
  0 => string 'henkie' (length=6)
  1 => string 'hiu' (length=3)

Comment: Not sure where you did you declare `$rowUSERS` array but you don't actually need that array, or this assignment `$rowUSERS[$x] = $_POST['addedUsers'][$x];`. You can directly use `$_POST['addedUsers'][$x]` in the INSERT query.

Comment: So I removed the extra variable, but it still doesn't work. Do you have any other recommendations?

Comment: You are open to SQL injections with this. You need to use parameterized queries throughout your code, not just for the first query. You need to be more specific then `error is somewhere around here~ish`. Have you echoed in the loop and confirmed it executes more then once? (Your question title isn't about SQL injections, it is SQL insertions).

Answer (score 0):

Edit:

I fixed it,
for some reason my group_id row in the DB had a primary key.

Sorry for bothering you guys,

~Lars